# -exec option of the find command does not work as expected on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, find

I am doing some practice on find command but I don't get the expected result when I attempt to use `-exec`option of it. The command I wrote just works without `-exec` option as the following:

```
$ find ~ \( -type f -not -perm 0600 \) -or \( -type d -name 'D*' \)
/home/baki/.bashrc
/home/baki/.bash_logout
/home/baki/.cache/motd.legal-displayed
/home/baki/.config/wslu/baseexec
/home/baki/.config/wslu/oemcp
/home/baki/.gitconfig
/home/baki/.landscape/sysinfo.log
/home/baki/.motd_shown
/home/baki/.profile
/home/baki/.ssh/known_hosts
/home/baki/.sudo_as_admin_successful
/home/baki/ssh_start
/home/baki/token
```

However, when I add the `-exec` option to the end of the command, it doesn't give any output:

```
find ~ \( -type f -not -perm 0600 \) -or \( -type d -name 'D*' \) -exec ls -l '{}' ';'
```

I have searched about it but I couldn't find a piece of useful information that can solve my problem.

Is my command wrong or is it about something else?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Works OK for me.

Comment: Wow, that's weird. I tried again but it didn't work. Thank you for trying by the way.

Comment: @Bodo thank you, i tried it and  now it works, i cant upvote since I'm new here but I can accept the answer if you write it as an answer :)

Comment: use `xargs` instead. `find .... | xargs ls -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `-and` operation has higher precedence than `-or`. Use extra parentheses:

```
find ~ \( \( -type f -not -perm 0600 \) -or \( -type d -name 'D*' \) \) -exec ls -l '{}' ';'
```

You can probably omit the inner parentheses in this case.